# Android Studio always ask for download system image

Tags: android, android-image, android-studio-3.0, android-virtual-device

I want to a create AVD in android studio but it shows message to select a system image and it show download option. When I download a image lets say Orio and then follow again create AVD process, it again gives same message with download link. Even though I select a image which was already downloaded, it does not allow me to click next/finish button.
Please find below screenshot of image list which shown while creating a AVD
[image]

When I checked list of images in SDK Manager, it show Orio is installed.
Please find below screenshot
[image]

Comment: Any chance you are under an user account, on your base operational system (MacOS?), without administrator privileges? Maybe this is mandatory. May worth an investigation. Because a non admin user may have it's configurations discharged boot time, for example.

Comment: SDK is different from emulator images. You need to download an emulator image to use an emulator. All emulator images can be found in the "x86 images" tab in your first image.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I found the solution for this issue. There is a checkbox(Show package Detail) in the 2nd screenshot above. If we click on that, it shows all the sub packages. There is an image listed in Android 8.1 Orio. I installed that image and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

### System image!

If you tick `[*]show Package Details`, it will shows a submenu and you can find out neither `system image` is installed or not.
If you want to make an *emulator*, make sure you ticked `system images`

[image: android studio scrshot]